# Nodal functionals in finite element analysis

Tags: finite-element, interpolation

I have a quintic Hermite basis functions [-1,1] for FEM applications, I wanted to check if it's nodal functionals are proper. Could someone explain nodal functionals in details and give an example of how to check them. By nodal functionals, I meant N_i[phi_j] = delta_ij, where phi_j are my basis functions on [-1,1]. Nodal functionals act on functions.

Here are my basis functions
[image]

And here is the interpolation of a simple sinusoid

[image]

I took zero'th, first and second derivatives of all of my basis functions and arrived at what looks like an identity matrix.
[image]

I presume for the fourth basis function Python could not do floating point arithmetic very well. However, it seems to be close to 0 and 1 accordingly.

```py
def N1(x):
  return -3*x**5/16 + 5*x**3/8 - 15*x/16 + 1/2

def dN1(x):
  return -15*x**4/16 + 15*x**2/8 - 15/16

def ddN1(x):
  return -60*x**3/16 + 30*x/8

def N2(x):
  return 3*x**5/16 - 5*x**3/8 + 15*x/16 + 1/2

def dN2(x):
  return 15*x**4/16 - 15*x**2/8 + 15/16

def ddN2(x):
  return 60*x/16 - 30*x/8

def N3(x):
  return -3*x**5/16 + x**4/16 + 5*x**3/8 - 3*x**2/8 - 7*x/16 + 5/16

def dN3(x):
  return -15*x**4/16 + 4*x**3/16 + 15*x**2/8 - 6*x/8 -7/16

def ddN3(x):
  return -60*x**3/16 + 12*x**2/16 + 30*x/8 - 6/8

def N4(x):
  return -3*x**5/16 - x**4/16 + 5*x**3/8 + 3*x**2/8 - 7*x/16 - 5/16

def dN4(x):
  return -15*x**4/16 - 4*x**3/16 + 15*x**2/8 + 6*x/7 - 7/16

def ddN4(x):
  return -60*x**3/16 - 12*x**2/16 + 30*x/8 + 6/8 

def N5(x):
  return -x**5/16 + x**4/16 + x**3/8 - x**2/8 - x/16 + 1/16

def dN5(x):
  return -5*x**4/16 + 4*x**3/16 + 3*x**2/8 - 2*x/8 - 1/16

def ddN5(x):
  return -20*x**3/16 + 12*x**2/16 + 6*x/8 - 2/8

def N6(x):
  return x**5/16 + x**4/16 - x**3/8 - x**2/8 + x/16 + 1/16

def dN6(x):
  return 5*x**4/16 + 4*x**3/16 - 3*x**2/8 - 2*x/8 + 1/16

def ddN6(x):
  return 20*x**3/16 + 12*x**2/16 - 6*x/8 - 2/8


funcs = [N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6]
```

Using these basis functions and calculating the following gave such answers

```py
print(N1(-1), N1(1), dN1(-1), dN1(1), ddN1(-1), ddN1(1))
print(N2(-1), N2(1), dN2(-1), dN2(1), ddN2(-1), ddN2(1))
print(N3(-1), N3(1), dN3(-1), dN3(1), ddN3(-1), ddN3(1))
print(N4(-1), N4(1), dN4(-1), dN4(1), ddN4(-1), ddN4(1))
print(N5(-1), N5(1), dN5(-1), dN5(1), ddN5(-1), ddN5(1))
print(N6(-1), N6(1), dN6(-1), dN6(1), ddN6(-1), ddN6(1))
```

Comment: I already checked the basis functions by interpolating a simple sinusoidal function, but I wanted to have a more mathematical approach, using nodal functionals.

Comment: What do you mean by "nodal functionals"? Are you referring to nodal basis functions? Also, "proper" refer to them being correct?

Comment: Yes, by nodal functionals, I meant N_i[phi_j] = delta_ij, where phi_j are my basis functions on [-1,1]. Nodal functionals act on functions.

Comment: Also, would be highly appreciated if someone could help me how to correctly create a macro mesh out of a refined mesh.

Comment: In your case, the functionals are $f \mapsto f(1)$, $f \mapsto f(-1)$, $f \mapsto f'(1)$, $f \mapsto f'(-1)$, $f \mapsto f''(1)$, and $f \mapsto f''(-1)$. Let's call them $\mathcal{L}_i$. You need to confirm that your basis functions $f_j$ satisfy $\mathcal{L}_i(f_j) = \delta_{ij}$. That is, for each basis element only one functional should evaluate to $1$ while the rest yields $0$.

Comment: If it's not too combersome, could you please elaborate a little more on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have functions $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ they satisfy the Lagrange property on $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ if $\phi_j(x_i) = \delta_{ij}$. This allows linear combinations of those $u(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n y_j\phi_j(x)$ to be interpolating at the points since
$$u(x_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \phi_j(x_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \delta_{ij} = y_i.$$

More generally, if you have functions
$$\phi_{0,1}, \ldots, \phi_{p,1}, \phi_{0,2},\ldots,\phi_{p,2}, \ldots, \phi_{0,n},\ldots,\phi_{p,n},$$
they satisfy the Hermite-Lagrange property of degree $p$ on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ if $$\frac{d^k\phi_{l,j}}{dx^l}(x_i) = \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}.$$
This means that the functions and their derivatives up to degree $p$ are interpolating at the points. This is the case since:
$$\frac{d^ku}{dx^k}(x_i) = \sum_{l=0}^p \sum_{j=0}^n y_{l,j}\frac{d^k\phi_{l,j}}{dx^k}(x_i) =
\sum_{l=0}^p \sum_{j=1}^n y_{l,j} \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl} = y_{k,i}.$$

In your case $x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 = 1$ and $\phi_{0,1}(x)$ is the first row and $\phi_{0,2}(x)$ is the second row of your matrix. You can check that $\phi_{0,j}(x_i) = \delta_{ij}$ by plugging $-1$ and $1$ in these polynomials. If this is indeed an Hermite polynomial you should also be able to verify that $\phi_{l,j}(x_i) = 0$ for $l\geq 0$ by taking derivatives and plugging in $-1$ and $1$. A similar thing holds for the remaining functions, except that the third and 4th probably interpolate first derivatives, and the last two interpolate the second derivatives at the endpoints.

The "nodal functionals" are just a fancy way of calling the evaluation functionals (composed with derivatives in the Hermite case) at the nodes. That is $N_i = \delta_{x_i}$ such that $N_i\phi_j = \delta_{x_i}\phi_j = \phi_j(x_i)$, or $N_{k,i} = \delta_{x_i} \circ \frac{d^k}{dx^k}$ such that
$$N_{k,i}\phi_{l,j} = \left(\delta_{x_i} \circ \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\right)\phi_{l,j}(x) = \frac{d^k\phi_{l,j}}{dx^k}(x_i).$$
With those you can write what I did in a fancy way:
$$N_{k,i}\phi_{l,j} = \frac{d^k\phi_{l,j}}{dx^l}(x_i)= \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}.$$

Comment: Do you mean I just need to plug in -1 and 1 to each of my basis functions and their respective first and second derivatives and when I plug these values in each of the basis functions, only one of them should 1, and the same goes for the second basis function and so on?

Comment: @NurbekSaidnassim Yes $\frac{d^k\phi_{l,j}}{dx^k}(x_i)$ should be one only for $i=j$ and $k=l$ and zero for the other $x_j$ and the other derivatives. In fact that's how you derive the above functions (there are also available closed-form expressions for the general Hermite-Lagrange basis functions too but they are not pretty).

Comment: @lightxbulb, yes that's what I explained in a previous post and how I derived the ones for the quintic interpolation.

Comment: @nicoguaro I have upvoted your answer some time ago - also the write up on your blog was a nice read. My understanding was that Nurbek was confused about the "nodal functionals" - he's probably reading some book/article that treats this with nodal functionals. They do that in some papers in order to define those on a reference element and elegantly get the transformation rules from that by using the fact that functionals transform covariantly under coordinate changes. If I remember correctly there was a paper that simplifed Argyris and Bell elements like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get it to work, first I thought, how would I get 6 x_i's for each basis function, then I thought maybe you meant first 2 basis functions I calculate by plugging in -1 and 1, then I take the derivatives of the 3rd and 4th basis functions and plug -1 and 1 and I should also get (1,0) and the same for the last 2 basis functions, but there I take the second derivatives of the last 2 basis functions and also plug in -1 and 1 and also should get (1,0), but my results were (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 26.25, 26.25, -26.25, -26.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Comment: I used the following N1(-1), N1(1), N2(-1), N2(1), dN3(-1), dN3(1), dN4(-1), dN4(1), ddN5(-1), ddN5(1), ddN6(-1), ddN6(1). Would it possible to show me where I got it wrong?

Comment: @NurbekSaidnassim This is a good opportunity to practice derivatives and some elementary algebra. I computed $\phi'_{1,0}(-1)$ and it gives one as desired, similarly $\phi'_{1,0}(1)$ gives a zero. I think you made some mistake to get $26.25$. You should however do 6 computations per basis function, not just two. You need to check the zero-th, first, and second derivative, at the two points, which makes six cases. All basis functions should be one only at their respective node and derivative, and zero otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed, I re-checked my code and I calculated the derivatives by hand and it solved the 26.25 problem, much appreciated. I will do as you said, hopefully, nodal functionals will be okay. Thank you.

Comment: By doing as you said, I got a 6x6 identity matrix, is it considered a correct solution for this problem? Since I didn't get one at their respective derivative. In @nicoguaro blog the solution seems to be so, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @NurbekSaidnassim I can guess what you mean but I would rather not presume. If you wish you can edit your question to clarify what you did and I can edit my answer to comment on the correctness of that. To begin with the "how to check them" from your initial question is not exactly clear what you want to check. I presumed you wanted to check the Hermite-Lagrange property, but I would rather you clarify that this is indeed what you want.

Comment: @lightxbulb I added what I could, I am not sure what you mean by Hermite - Lagrange property, I hope this clarifies something.

Comment: The point was to use nodal functionals to check if the quintic Hermite basis functions are correct.

Comment: @NurbekSaidnassim "I am not sure what you mean by Hermite - Lagrange property" - yet it is in my answer. The requirement that the matrix that you printed be equal to the identity is the Hermite-Lagrange property in matrix form, i.e. the interpolation property of the basis functions w.r.t. the nodal functionals. Unsurprisingly you have a typo in dN4 which lead you to a non-identity matrix. It's not floating point precision, it's just sloppy coding.

Comment: Now it's all identity. My apologies. Indeed I divided by the wrong number. So, the identity matrix would mean that nodal functionals are correct, right? @lightxbulb

Comment: @NurbekSaidnassim It's not about "functions being correct" - the Hermite-Lagrange (HL) property being satisfied tells you that your shape functions are interpolating on the nodes (in your case you interpolate pointwise or derivative data). There are reasons to desire that, but one could use non-interpolating functions just fine too. HL makes prescribing pointwise and derivative data very simple, and gluing elements together in a continuous manner. For example if you make the derivatives agree at inner nodes of your mesh then you can have a $C^2$ space for your solution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to coarsify the mesh such that the solution would be $C^2$?

Comment: @NurbekSaidnassim That's an entirely separate question that probably deserves its own thread. Also it's not done by coarsifying the mesh - you just tie the derivatives at the inner nodes which reduces the degrees of freedom by 2 in your case by per inner node.